# Why is this backbone view not rendering correctly?

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a couple of views in backbone.js and I want want to be a child of the other. So I've created the following code.

```
var app = app || {} ;

app.ProjectCardView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('.list'),

    template: _.template( $("#tpl-project-card-summary").html() ),


    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        return this.$el.html( this.template() );

    }

});


app.DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('.contentwrap'),

    template: _.template( $("#tpl-dashboard").html() ),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        this.addProjects();
    },

    render: function() {
        //console.log(this.template());
         this.$el.html( this.template() );

    },

    addProjects: function() {
        var pcv = new app.ProjectCardView();    
    }



});

app.dash = new app.DashboardView;
```

The DashboardView renders perfectly, but when I create the ProjectCardView, the view doesn't seem to initialise so the template is empty and el is not set. If I set el in the initialize function, then $el is still not set. I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: looks like I found the issue; $('.list') is an element introduced by the first view, as such, it's not rendered by the time the second view is trying to find it - even though the first view has rendered in the DOM.

So how do I fix that?

Comment: Can you post your templates?

Comment: I'd rather not - even if I remove the templates, it still doesn't fire correctly.

Comment: Without seeing your html it is hard to help... You can try change your ProjectCardView's `el` from `el: $('.list'),` to `el: '.list',`

Comment: @nemesv awesome - that's totally fixed it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specify your el as a  jQuery selector `$('.list')` you should know that it will be executed when your `Backbone.View.extend` is executed. So if your element is not in the DOM by that time your selector won't work.

So you need to specify the `el` when it is in the DOM. So in your case you can write:

```
addProjects: function() {
    var pcv = new app.ProjectCardView({ el: $('.list') });    
}
```

Or you can use the Backbone feature that you can specify the `el` as a string istead of the jQuery selector:

```
app.ProjectCardView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    el: '.list',
    //...
}
```